# Jetty custom authentication

Tags: java, authentication, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm trying out jetty, embedded in my Java application.

I would like to be able to authenticate a user using a simple HTTP GET request including the login info. For instace:

```
http://host/login?user=foo&psw=bar
```

What's the best way to do this? Should I create a custom `Authenticator` class? What's the best base class to start from and what to override?

Comment: Hi, I just want to make sure that you are aware that this type of authentication can be easily eavesdropped on, especially as you are not using https, and as well, all the user's credentials may be listed in the access logs, if you have access logs turned on, or do anything to log the URL of incoming requests.

Comment: Yes, of course. This is just a simplified example of what I actually need to do and, anyway, there will be HTTPS involved :) But thanks for the concern :)

Comment: When I need to do some custom authentication, I typically use a Filter. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html   They are pretty easy to use, and allow you to roll your own authentication any way you like, and you can even attach a user principal to the request.  (This means you can use the standard getUserPrincipal() from your servlet.)  In your case, your filter would just check the query parameters against a database and then doFilter().

Comment: @Jamie But then how am I gonna make use of the `LoginService`s available? Besides, I'm a bit confused with all the modules in jetty: It looks like Filters, Handlers, Authenticators, ... are somehow interchangeable. How are they related to each other? What is supposed to be used for what? Do you have some references explaining the global structure? Thanks